# The correct way to implement bulma-pageloader in nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bulma

So this is my code:

```html
<template>
    <div class="pageloader is-active">
      <span class="title">Pageloader</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'bulma-extensions/bulma-pageloader/dist/css/bulma-pageloader.min.css';

export default{
    beforeMount: {

    },
    mounted: {

    }

}
</script>
```

I couldn't get the `pageloader` to show up. Did i miss something?

**Note:** All dependency is already there.

**Update:** This is how I implement the extension based on [estevanj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3718595/estevanj) solution.

**pageloader.vue** [components]

```html
    <template>
      <div class="pageloader" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active' : loading}">
        <span class="title">Pageloader</span>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data: () => ({
        loading: false
      }),
      methods: {
        start() {
          this.loading = true;
        },
        finish() {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

**main.sass** [assets/css]

```html
    @import '~bulma';
    @import '~bulma-extensions/bulma-pageloader/dist/css/bulma-pageloader.sass';
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```html
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading:  '~/components/PageLoader.vue',

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.sass'
  ],
```

Comment: What happens if you try to load the div and span without any class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom loading like this one:
https://nuxtjs.org/examples/custom-loading/

You can use the bulma one inside the custom :)